# Why is $\log(\log^*(n)) = Ω(\log^*\log(n))$ is true while $\log^*\log n$ is bigger than $\log \log^*n$?

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

In field of algorithm and data structure I came across this problem.
As far as I know

$$\lg^* \lg n > \lg \lg^* n$$

is true in term of growth rate
and also noticed that

$$\log(\log^*(n)) = Ω(\log^*\log(n))$$

is True which means that $\lim f(n)/g(n)$ where $n$ goes to infinity in this case is infinity, meaning that growth rate of $\log(\log^*(n))$ is faster than $(\log^*\log(n))$ that is completely opposite to the previous term.
Can someone explain?

Comment: You can enclose your equations in `$` signs to format them. I reformatted your question. Feel free to [Edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4766230/edit) or rollback the question if I misinterpreted you!

Comment: Are you sure you have the right definition for $\Omega$?

Comment: i think so, Ω is true when f is bigger than g but in this case it reveresed, i dont know i need explanation

Comment: What is $\log^*(n)$?

Answer (score 2):

Note $\log^*(\log n)=(\log^* n)-1$ so you're comparing $(\log^*n)-1$ to $\log(\log^*n)$. Writing $\ell=\log^*n$, this is comparing $\ell-1$ to $\log \ell$; obviously $\ell-1$ will dominate $\log\ell$, so your second equality (asymptotic) is backwards, it should be $\log^*\log n=\Omega(\log\log^*n)$, which says $\log^*\log n$ is bounded below by / not dominated by $\log\log^* n$.

Comment: ty for ur time and answer! this was a question in "Masters entrance exam " and the two possible answer for it was either small o or Big Omega i thaugh it might be small o due to this conditions but in answers it says that Big Omega is true. that was what confused me and i think they are wrong based on your answer. once again Thank you for your help